# Push notification postman InvalidApnsCredential ios

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I receive InvalidApnsCredential after trying to send a push to the device. I verified the key id, team id, bundle id, everything is ok...

{
"to" : "frK6tcKU3Uz1lYhzKWkQGe:APA91bF6Yk7AjYPvkWnfWH_3cSEsxZoniD2IrhgsVC4kCFxpzqxe6SRQMfBzmBJKVIBGOpIeU4VOlybLwSU0AIaCPH7LxhPyclyIKXU7qkIP2XZE2lyzpI7R85vNMQHZiixVYmsfyYhn",
"notification" : {
"body_loc_key" : "ALERT_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_BALANCE_AND_MOVEMENT_ALERT",
"title_loc_key": "BALANCE_AND_MOVEMENT_ALERT_TITLE",
"sound" : "default"
}
}

Answer (score 0):

When you add a custom Provisioning profile from Apple to your app, there is
App ID Prefix (Team ID), make sure that this APP ID Prefix and Team id in Firebase console is same.